# Authorize.Net ARB API get status of recurrent payments

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, authorize.net, recurring-billing, authorize.net-arb

I am using authorize.net`s ARB api.

I was wondering is there another way to get status of recurent payment except emails and Silent post?

If I have the following scenario:

My server is down for maintenance when the silent post request is sent. May I make some call to the ARB api to take the status of passed payments?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Transaction Details API](http://developer.authorize.net/api/transaction_details/) for:

- Batch settlement information, including statistics broken out by payment type.
- Limited transaction details for specific batch requests.
- Full transactional details for specific transaction IDs.
- Limited transaction details for unsettled transactions.
- Batch statistics by payment type for a specified batch ID.

A combination of these can be used for reporting and reconciling transactions including those made by subscriptions.